# How to get the position of selected character or String in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to know how can I get the x,y position of the selected character or String in 
`EditText`. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by the "x,y position"?

Answer (score 5):

Use this code to get the first index of a certain character:

```
String s = editText.getText().toString();
int position = s.indexOf("C");              // where C is your character to be searched
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about the *selected* text

Comment: he is asking for x,y position.

Comment: this answer absolutely out of question.

Comment: This is unrelated to the meaning of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to get the `x` *and* `y` coordinates of a specific character in a TextView, should work for EditText as well. `offset` is the index of the desired character in the view's text.

```
Layout layout = editView.getLayout();
if (layout == null) { // Layout may be null right after change to the view
    // Do nothing
}

int lineOfText = layout.getLineForOffset(offset);
int xCoordinate = (int) layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(offset);
int yCoordinate = layout.getLineTop(lineOfText);
```